# Select all users from database and put dates to select options

Tags: php, angularjs

Hello I am trying to do simple role system to my website.

I want to put all my useres from database to field where I can choose one of them and add something for this specific user

What I have? Connection to db, inserting, deleting etc.

I Created simple select form where I want to put users.

This field is only for Admin role.

```
  <?php if($_SESSION['type']=='Admin') { ?>
                 <md-input-container flex="50">
                    <label>Choose user from db</label>
                    <md-select name="user" ng-model="user" required>
                        <md-option value="user1">user1 to choose</md-option>
                        <md-option value="user2">user2 to choose</md-option>
                    </md-select>
                </md-input-container>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

This part with session type works fine. And only admin is allowed to see this part.

But how Can I assign useres to values?

my table looks like
ID name username password where name = name and surname and username = login. I can work on name or username whatever.

Somebody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have you data from the database. You can simply do a loop:

```
             <md-input-container flex="50">
                <label>Choose user from db</label>
                <md-select name="user" ng-model="user" required>
                  @foreach ($users as $user)  
                    <md-option value="{{ $user.id }}">{{ $user.name }}</md-option>
                  @endforeach
                </md-select>
            </md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i Did something like that

```
<?php if($_SESSION[ 'type']=='Admin' ) { ?>
                <md-input-container flex="50">
                    <label>Choose user</label>
                    <md-select name="username" ng-model="" required>
                        <?php $res=mysqli_query($link, "select * from login"); while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { ?>

                        <md-option>
                            <?php echo $row[ "username"]; ?>
                        </md-option>

                        <?php } ?>
                    </md-select>
                </md-input-container>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <?php } ?>
```

But when  I choose for example user: Nelson there isn't show in option. How can I assing it to field?